# Evaluation of a simple limit with Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, limits

I would like to evaluate $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^{\sin x} - \sin^2x - 1}{x}$$
using Taylor Series expansion in a completely rigorous way.
What would a rigorous version of the following argument look like?

From
$$e^{\sin x} -1\sim_0 e^x-1 \sim_0 x \text{ and }\sin^2x \sim_0 x^2$$
we can find the limit
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^{\sin x} - \sin^2x - 1}{x} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{x-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x} = 1.$$

In particular I'm not exactly sure how to deal with Landau symbols $o$ and $O$ in nested functions.

Comment: Expand in this way $e^x=1+x+x^2/2!+\cdots$, $\sin x=x-x^3/3!+\cdots$. You only need to focus on the first order terms. I read a Chinese book called "estimation of order", helped me alot. It could help to find yourself a similar book with the key word "asymptotic expansion".

Comment: Yes please, Git Gud.

Comment: @rehband I should have read your question more attentively. I deleted my comment before you answered, but the answer to my question was obvious.

Comment: @Git Gud Okay, no worries :)

Comment: Are you familiar with the arithmetic properties of the big Oh notation? For instance do you know that $O(x^2)+O(x^2)=O(x^2)$?

Comment: I don't know very much about big Oh notation. (I do know the fact that you posted though).

Comment: @rehband It's sufficient. See the answers below.

Comment: @rehband By the way, an alternative method is to simply note that the limit equals $f'(0)$ for an appropriate function $f$ which you'll have no trouble identifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sin(x) = x + o(x)$, then $\sin^2(x) = x^2 + 2xo(x) + (o(x))^2 = x^2 + o(x)$, since $$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{2xo(x)+ (o(x))^2}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}(2o(x)+(\dfrac{o(x)}{x})^2x = 0$$

$e^{\sin(x)} = 1+ \sin(x) + o(\sin(x)) = 1 + x + o(x) + o(x+ o(x)) = 1+ x + o(x)$, since

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{o(x)+ o(x + o(x))}{x} =  \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{o(x)}{x} + \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{o(x + o(x))}{x + o(x)}\dfrac{x+o(x)}{x} = 0$$

Thus $e^{\sin(x)} - \sin^2(x) -1 = x - x^2 + o(x)$

Answer (score 2):

You can write
$$\sin(x)=x+O(x^2)$$
$$\sin^2 x=\left(x+O(x^2)\right)^2=O(x^2)$$
$$\exp(x)=1+x+O(x^2)$$
$$\exp (\sin x)=\exp \left(x+O(x^2)\right)=1+\left(x+O(x^2)\right)+O(x^2)=1+x+O(x^2)$$

Thus

$$\frac{e^{\sin x} - \sin^2x - 1}{x}=\frac{1+x-1+O(x^2)}x=\frac{x+O(x^2)}x \\
=1+O(x)\rightarrow 1$$